# Many rows into one row (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I generated the pairs as follows:

```
      vec1 = ('A':'C');
      vec2 = ('A':'C');
      [p,q] = meshgrid(vec1, vec2);
      out = [p(:) q(:)]
```

The pairs are in many rows as below :

```
     pairs =
               AA
               AB
               AC
               BA
               BB
               BC
               CA
               CB
               CC
```

How can I get the pairs which are formated in 1 row like this:

```
      pairs = AAABACBABBBCCACBCC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TUT (Transpose, unroll, transpose):

```
>> out = out.';
>> pairs = out(:).'

pairs =

AAABACBABBBCCACBCC
```

How the above works is that unrolling something, or using `(:)`, in MATLAB converts an N-Dimensional array into a single vector.  This is done in column-major format, so columns of a matrix are stacked on top of each other to form a single vector.   However, you want to stack all of the rows together into a single row.  We can do this by first transposing the matrix so the rows become columns, then unrolling on the transpose so that the columns are stacked on top of each other.  This is your desired result, but it's a single column and so you need to transpose this result to get what you want.

Alternatively, you can use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) on the transpose and make sure that we get a single row for the output:

```
>> pairs = reshape(out.', 1, [])

pairs =

AAABACBABBBCCACBCC
```